# SQL statement using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have these kinds of tables:

Customer1:

```
"Customer1" table:
--------------------------------
id   |    branch    |  company_id
--------------------------------
1    |    typical   |     1
2    |    natural   |     8
--------------------------------
```

Customer2

```
"Customer2"  table:
-------------------------------
id  |   company  |  group_id
-------------------------------
1   |     deux   |    1
-------------------------------
```

Customer3

```
"Customer3"   table:
-------------------------------
id    |    group
-------------------------------
1     |    alpha   
-------------------------------
```

Now, how can I have an output using sql command/statement base from the tables like this one :

```
----------------------------
group | company | branch
----------------------------
alpha | deux    | typical
```

Comment: Can you have multiple rows in each table for a customer iD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for- However this may not be what you are looking for if tables have multiple records for same id

```
SELECT  C3.group, C2.company, C1.branch
FROm    Customer1 c1 INNER JOIN
        Customer2 c2    ON  c1.company_id = c2.id INNER JOIN
        Customer3 c3    ON  c2.group_id = c3.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like

```
SELECT  [group], 
        [company], 
        [branch] 
FROm    Customer1 c1 INNER JOIN
        Customer2 c2    ON  c1.company_id = c2.id INNER JOIN
        Customer3 c3    ON  c2.group_id = c3.id
```

To ensure that you always show all the values, you might want to take a look at using `LEFT JOINS`

Something like

```
SELECT  [group], 
        [company], 
        [branch] 
FROm    Customer1 c1 LEFT JOIN
        Customer2 c2    ON  c1.company_id = c2.id LEFT JOIN
        Customer3 c3    ON  c2.group_id = c3.id
```

Here is a nice article that explains the difference between the various JOIN types

[Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

The example-values you gave us would not result in any matches if you run a join because the IDs don't match. However this is what the query would look like

```
select [group], company, branch 
from Customer3 c3 
join Customer2 c2 on c3.ID = c2.group_id
join Customer1 c1 on c2.id = c1.company_id
```